# Can degree of irreducible polynomial be lower than the degree of the field extension?

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

$x^3 -2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $3$. And  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 3$

However, $x^3-1$ is reducible, it equals $(x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$.  So the degree of the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ satisfied by $\omega = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{3} i}{2}$ is $2$.  But the vector space basis is $\{1,\omega, \omega^2\}$ so $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}] = 3$.

Have I made a mistake or can the degrees not match?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you!

Comment: A side comment: It is true that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))$ has dimension $\deg f - 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. A basis is given by $1,x,\dots,x^{\deg f -1}$, where $x$ denotes the class of $X$. But this quotient ring is only a field when $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: @DouglasMolin You meant dimension $\deg f$, not $\deg f-1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry..... Silly mistake